# Why can't I read this csv file into R

Tags: r

I'm very new to R and I'm trying to read a csv file and I keep getting this message. I think I've set the right working directory, and it seems like it's an issue with file permissions. As far as I can tell I have write permission for this file. Not sure how to resolve this issue.

```html
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'data.table'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     between, first, last
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     transpose
setwd("C:\\Users\\Lee\\Documents\\R\\housing")
housing_census_2016 <- read_csv("C:\\Users\\Lee\\Documents\\R\\housing\\housing_census_2016")
#> Warning in file(con, "rb"): cannot open file 'C:/Users/Lee/Documents/R/housing/
#> housing_census_2016': Permission denied
#> Error in file(con, "rb"): cannot open the connection
```

Comment: Is your filename present in `list.files()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include the file extension in your call to `read_csv`

Simply add it to the filename, so the full command looks like

`housing_census_2016 <- read_csv("C:\\Users\\Lee\\Documents\\R\\housing\\housing_census_2016.csv")`

Comment: Ok, this was a lot easier than I thought! Thank you!

Comment: although since OP had already set the working directory I'd recommend just `read_csv("housing_census_2016.csv")`

Comment: @LeeW, if this answered your question please consider accepting it to resolve your question.